# Graphviz error now breaking schemaspy db generation

Tags: graphviz, schemaspy

I have been using Schemaspy(v5.0) to diagram mySQL(v5.7.11) using Graphviz via Homebrew on my Mac (El Capitan).  A recent update to Graphviz(v2.40.1) apparently has broken Schemaspy's ability to generate the relational diagrams.

```
Writing/graphing summary.....org.schemaspy.util.Dot$DotFailure: 'dot -Tpng:gd 
/Tools/docs/data/project/diagrams/summary/relationships.real.compact.dot 
-o/Tools/docs/data/project/diagrams/summary/relationships.real.compact.png 
-Tcmapx' 
failed with return code 139
```

To solve this issue, I have tried:

- uninstall/reinstall graphviz
- downgrade Graphviz(v2.38 - it was the only version I could find and homebrew didn't have any older versions either) but it hosed my install
- attempted to run on a colleague's computer with same results
- tried the new beta version of schemaspy(v6.0-beta3)
- searched graphviz forums (page crashed), stackoverflow, and general google search.

Looking to figure out how to get this working again.

---

[Edit]
I didn't find a solution to why SchemaSpy/Graphviz stopped working (or wtf "code 139" meant), but I did use a workaround.

- Install Docker
- Get mnuessler/schemaspy or similar from hub.docker.com
- open a volume to your host - it will be used in the docker command
- run the command below

`docker run -it --rm -v /docs/data:/data mnuessler/schemaspy -hq
 -t mysql -host localhost -u root -p root -db things -o /data/leads`

where -v is the volume you opened on your host and -o /data/... is where the output will show up after the run

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default SchemaSpy expects the dot executable to be in the PATH environment variable. Use this option to explicitly specify where Graphviz is installed.

If you don't want to add it to your PATH, you can use -gv parameter and provide path to where Graphviz is installed.

### Update

- If you're using GraphViz version 2.40.1 on OS X version older than High Sierra, add `-renderer :quartz` to the commandline.
- If you're using GraphViz version 2.40.1 on OS X version High Sierra or newer, add `-renderer :cairo` to the commandline.

Comment: I installed using homebrew, which places the app in the $PATH, and everything was working just fine until the last Graphviz update.


To check:

`$ dot -V

dot - graphviz version 2.40.1 (20161225.0304)`

thanks for the response

Comment: Additional update - I added the brew path to the schemaspy script:
`-gv "/usr/local/Cellar/graphviz/2.40.1/"`

and got the same error messages.

I'll keep at it - thanks anyhow!

Comment: This issue happen also for other SchemaSpy user. I try to find where is the bug and try to fix it as soon as possible. Please verify status of this issue on Github https://github.com/schemaspy/schemaspy/issues/33

Comment: It will be work by using -renderer :quartz tested on Mac OS El Capitan with graphviz version 2.40.1 (20161225.0304)

Comment: Gave the green check for the above comment

thanks all for reviewing

Comment: I'm running on mojave, graphviz 2.40.1 and tried using brew to install graphviz. the pango libraries were missing in the brew install (they were removed in latest version of graphviz), ultimately had to switch to macports installation of graphviz in order to get schemaspy to work.

Comment: SchemaSpy v. 6.1.0 from [documentation](https://schemaspy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/new.html#id2): "Now has option to use embedded viz.js (no need for Graphviz) `-vizjs`"

Answer (score 6):

**Version 6.1.0 of SchemaSpy has removed the dependency on GraphViz, so you can avoid this problem by using this version.**

---

Version 6.1.0 includes a JavaScript implementation of GraphViz which can be used instead of looking for GraphViz on the PATH.

I'm not sure whether the JavaScript version is used by default, but you can force this behaviour by supplying a `-vizjs` argument, e.g.

```
java -jar ./schemaspy-6.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -vizjs -t pgsql -o output 
    -host localhost -port 5432 -s public -db my_db -u root -p password 
    -dp jdbc/postgresql-42.2.6.jar
```

The JavaScript implementation relies on the Nashorn JavaScript engine, which was removed from the JDK in version 15, so you must use JDK <= 14.

Comment: This works fine for me. Thank you.

Comment: -vizjs works fine for me either

Answer (score 4):

Working fix on High Sierra for this:

`brew uninstall graphviz`

After that run:

`brew install graphviz --with-librsvg --with-pango`

Source:https://github.com/schemaspy/schemaspy/issues/33/#issuecomment-355091538

Comment: The `--with...` options seem to be broken with recent versions of hombrew/graphviz:

https://github.com/parrt/dtreeviz/issues/33

Answer (score 1):

IF you are on macOs HighSierra the correct call is without the renderer and (re)install Graphviz with:

`brew reinstall graphviz --with-librsvg --with-pango`

Answer (score 1):

I tried the above methods, but it wasn't working for me.

Running on mojave, I wasn't able to get the `brew` installation to work (due to missing pango libraries). Maybe this will be updated in the future, but at the time of this writing, I had to switch to the Macports installation and this worked for me.

Also running schemaspy 6.0.0, and Graphviz 2.40.1.

Answer (score 1):

Installing graphviz with brew now (as of 2021) installs both librsvg and pango by default. No need to pass the `--with-*` options: they are not valid anymore either, as others have commented.

Just run `brew install graphviz` and ensure you're using the correct renderer option, per accepted answer and project FAQs.

Mac version: Catalina 10.15.7

Full dependency list:

```
==> Installing dependencies for graphviz: libpng, freetype, fontconfig, jpeg, libtiff, giflib, webp, gd, gettext, libffi, pcre, gdbm, mpdecimal, ca-certificates, openssl@1.1, readline, sqlite, xz, python@3.9, glib, jasper, netpbm, gts, pkg-config, libpthread-stubs, xorgproto, libxau, libxdmcp, libxcb, libx11, libxext, libxrender, lzo, pixman, cairo, gdk-pixbuf, fribidi, gobject-introspection, graphite2, icu4c, harfbuzz, pango, librsvg, m4 and libtool
```

Answer (score 0):

Update for this question.   Homebrew recently made changes to adding of options when installing a package....they don't allow it anymore.  :)

https://brew.sh/2019/02/02/homebrew-2.0.0/

The suggestion was to use `brew edit graphviz` and add the desired arguments there.  I'm trying that now.